# Not being able to make an integer greater than another one

Tags: python

I'm making a program that gives you different basic operations to solve.
If you choose subtraction, it also gives you a choice if negative numbers are allowed or not. If the user says "No", it's supposed to change the variable that determines the minuend to a different number and check if it's greater than the subtrahend, and if it isn't, it tries again.

I've tried using a while loop that keeps regenerating the minuend until it's greater than the  subtrahend, I've tried placing after FAT1 (minuend) = random.randint(1,50) > FAT2 (subtrahend) or FAT1 = random.randint(1,50 > FAT2).
I've also tried placing it in a function, or making a boolean used in the while loop instead of FAT1 < FAT2, but it keeps not working.

Variables I made throughout (all global):

```
FAT1 = first number (int)
FAT2 = second number (int)
OPER = the operation the user chooses (string)
NEG = if the user chooses yes or no to negative numbers (string)
```

Problematic part of the code:

```
    #No negative numbers
    elif NEG == "NO" or "No" or "no" or "nO" :
        while True :
            FAT1 = random.randint(1,50)
            FAT2 = random.randint(1,50)
            #Here it takes what the user typed and converts it in an int
            TYP = input()
            NUM = int(TYP)
            while FAT1 < FAT2 :
                FAT1 = random.randint(1,50)
            RES = FAT1 - FAT2
            print("What's",FAT1," - ",FAT2)
            if NUM == RES :
                print("Correct!")
            elif NUM != RES :
                print("Wrong! Try again!")
```

EDIT: As I said in my comment:
I get the input before the problem gets made because the user may choose a different operation. This question could be clearer with the whole code, but i didn't feel like putting it all there because it felt redundant Here's the code: pastebin.com/ZfqhY2md

EDIT2: I tried making this dictionary at the beginning (all in one line):

```
dict = {'Addition': 'Addition', 'Subtraction': 'Subtraction', 'No': 'No', 
'Yes': 'Yes'}
```

And at the beginning of every if statement i tried this:

```
if NEG == dict.get('Yes') :
```

And it works for every suite except the one with No to negative numbers...
New full code here:
https://pastebin.com/600TpkZe

Comment: Hmmm, there's a lot going on here. Why do you get the input *before* you print out the subtraction problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you clean up the question a bit. **What do you mean by:** "a program that gives you different basic operations to solve" be a little more concrete - or **add more code**. When is OPER used?

Comment: Why not `FAT1 = random.randint(FAT2,50)`?

Comment: I get the input before the problem gets made because the user may choose a different operation. This question could be clearer with the whole code, but i didn't feel like putting it all there because it felt redundant
Here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/ZfqhY2md

Comment: I tried FAT1 = random.randint(FAT2,50) , it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is a duplicate...
I made a tuple for any No you might type and check with:
(Notup is the list of NOs)

```
if OPER in Notup :
```

Then I made tuples for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in your `elif` condition.

Checking: `NEG == "NO" or "No" or "no" or "nO"` is going to return `True` if, and only if, `NEG = 'NO'`

rather try:
`elif NEG.upper() == 'NO':`

Comment: Actually, the asker's statement is *always* going to be true, because `"No"`, `"no"`, and `"nO"` are all truthy values.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. It'll be unable to produce False. That being said I still doubt whether this is the intended condition. The rest of the code seems to be running fine for me though (given this snippet)